# Set custom parent taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, hierarchy, taxonomy

There is few custom post_taxonomies for "property" post type like features, neighborhoods, statuses, etc. For "States" and "Cities" is set 'hierarchical' => true, and it works great. But I want to change parents for "Cities" to "States" to /group sort Cities by States.
All I can do - add new option to choose "State" for city, but this solution can't group cities by states.
Is there any solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I add 'State' as 'term_meta'and use 'get_term_meta' function and make all listings which i want.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create heirarchical relationships between different taxonomies' terms.

One solution would be to create a 'Location' taxonomy and put your states in as parent terms, and cities as sub-terms. You can then create a listing for just the states by using the following query:

```
$states = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'location',
    'parent' => 0,
) );
```